# How to use attributes to denote an array of keywords in Nest

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I've got a property of type `string[]`. I want its members not analysed, i.e of type `Keyword`

how can I use attributes to inform Nest of my intention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the [`[Keyword]` attribute](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/attribute-mapping.html); Elasticsearch makes no distinction between a field having a single value or an array of multiple values

Comment: Can you please also link to the page that documents this behavior?

Comment: Sure, here's the Elasticsearch documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html

Comment: Thank you very much. The elasticsearch documentation, while well organized, is full of cryptic ways to explain simple concepts.